# Javascript: Insert a character in a string every nth

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to insert a character in a string every nth index.  Basically just formatting a number from 1000 to 1,000 OR 100,0

This is what I have so far.  Tried a few variations but this is the closest I have gotten.  What am I missing?

Here is a link to a jsFiddle with the function in use:
https://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/t0ug5msv/

```
// function to insert value at specific index
function addCharacter(str, character, index, from) {
  // convert the str to an array
  var strArray = str.split("");

  // loop through array
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // find array index matching index and insert character
    if(i % index == 0) {
      strArray.splice(i + 1, 0, character);
    }
  }

  return strArray.join("");
}
```

Comment: In your code, if(i % index == 0)
Don't forget that 0 % everynumber is 0, so you will always splice the first character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to format a number, instead of rolling your own solution, you could rely on JavaScript's built-in features:

```js
var myNumber = '1000000';
var formattedNumber = Number(myNumber).toLocaleString();

console.log(formattedNumber); // "1,000,000"
```

[Docs for `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex or built-in formatting functions:

```
function addCharacter(str, character, index, from) {
    // Split string
    var strArray = str.split("")

    // New array to push into. splicing will cause problems with indexes.
    var _array = [];

    // Flip array to start from the opposite side
    if (from === 'right') { strArray.reverse(); }

    // Loop through string
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // Always push the next character
        _array.push(strArray[i]);

        // Mod index should be 0
        // Current index should not be 0
        // and don't add a character at the end
        if ((i + 1) % index === 0 && i != 0 && (i + 1) < str.length) {
            _array.push(character);
        }
    }

    // _array will be reversed because strArray was reversed so flip it back
    if (from === 'right') { _array.reverse(); }

    // return the new array!
    return _array.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and insert the wanted sting.

```js
function beautify(s, n, v) {
    return s.replace(new RegExp('.{' + n + '}(?=.)', 'g'), '$&' + v);
}

console.log(beautify('12345678', 3, '#'));
```

Comment: Since number formatting is right to left, then yours starts from the opposite side of string.

Comment: You're right I found that out from the selected answer. :)